# biber in tool mode: Specify data source when creating .bib file containing cited references

Tags: bibtex, biber, jabref

As this might turn out to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I will try to give as much additional information as possible. But to start with, my question is:

- **Question (Y)**: How can I make `biber` (in tool mode) create a `.bib` file based on a `.bcf` file and using *another* `.bib` file as data source than the one specified in the `.bcf` file?

---

## Question and Background (X):

Recently, I started to use JabRef for bibliography management. On the one hand, the fact that it uses `.bib` as database format is very handy, but on the other hand there are some drawbacks:

- All meta information is contained in that `.bib` file, including file references, personal comments and database specific configuration. For some reasons (I think they don't matter here) I want to use a "clean" `.bib` file for my projects, containing only the relevant bibliographical data. As a consequence, I need to create a "reduced" version of the database `.bib` file which leads to the next point:
- [JabRef has no option to add custom BibTeX export filters](http://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/discussion/318825/thread/3730dc6e/#4698/2473/2c35). Of course, it is possible to [export a subset of the bibliography in BibTeX format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82554/jabref-can-it-export-a-subset-of-the-bibliography-in-bibtex-format) but this does not solve the issue of having configuration data and personal fields in the new file. I know that the latter issue could by solved with JabRef's "Set/clear/rename fields" feature but this is only a partial solution and very cumbersome when it needs to be done repeatedly.
- I would prefer to have only references that are actually *used* in a project's `.bib` file. That means I need to [create a `.bib` file containing only the cited references of a bigger `.bib` file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file).

### The Goal

So what I want is:

- Manage my bibliography in JabRef.
- Write a LaTeX document using `biblatex` with `biber`.
- Generate a `.bib` file containing only the references cited in the document as a subset of my JabRef database.
- (Remove all fields containing superfluous information from that smaller `.bib` file. This is *not part of the current question*; I only mentioned it above as one of the reasons why I *want* to do all this.)

### What I have so far

Basically, I found three different approaches to my problem:

- Approach 1: Use [`bibtool`](http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/index.en.html) to reduce the `.bib` file. Problem: `bibtool` is not designed to be used with BibLaTeX/biber, see [Using BibTool with BibLaTeX, again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113838/using-bibtool-with-biblatex-again).
- Approach 2: Use JabRef's feature "New subdatabase based on AUX file". Again, this is not compatible with `biber`.
- Approach 3: [Use `biber` in tool mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212134/37118).

---

Approach 3 *almost* did the trick. The following command takes all references cited in `paper.tex` and writes them to `paper_biber.bib`:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve paper.bcf
```

However, recall that I want to have *two* `.bib` files: A reduced file (`paper_biber.bib`) automatically created from the `.bcf` file and besides a master/database file `master.bib` containing *all* my references.

That means, in `paper.tex` I have a line like `\addbibresource{paper_biber.bib}`. Accordingly, `biber` writes the following into `paper.bcf`

```
<bcf:bibdata section="0">
    <bcf:datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex">paper_biber.bib</bcf:datasource>
  </bcf:bibdata>
```

and when I run `biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve paper.bcf`, `biber` looks for the data of the references from `paper.bcf` in `paper_biber.bib`. **But this is the wrong file.** I need `biber` to look for the data of the references from `paper.bcf` in `master.bib`.

When I manually edit `paper.bfc` and replace `paper_biber.bib` by `master.bib`

```
<bcf:bibdata section="0">
    <bcf:datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex">master.bib</bcf:datasource>
  </bcf:bibdata>
```

I get exactly the desired result, namely `paper_biber.bib` containing all the entries from `master.bib` that are referenced in `paper.bcf`.

Unfortunately, manually editing `paper.bcf` is not very convenient and difficult to automate. This brings me back to the original question:

> How can I make `biber` (in tool mode) create a `.bib` file based
>   on a `.bcf` file and using *another* `.bib` file as data source than
>   the one specified in the `.bcf` file?

I tried to find an appropriate command line option in the [`biber` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) and in `biber --help` but could not find anything useful.

I suppose that I could use a `biber.conf` file which, according to the manual, should overrule any settings in the `.bcf` file but I have no clue what I have to write in that file. I tried the following with no effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <!-- SECTION 0 -->
  <bibdata section="0">
    <datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex">master.bib</datasource>
  </bibdata>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself and it is surprisingly trivial: The option `--input-directory` specifies the directory where `biber` looks for source files.

The only limitation is that the reduced `.bib` file and the full file need to have the same name. Then, the solution is:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex --input-directory "path/to/database/" --output_resolve paper.bcf
```

---

**EDIT**: The command above is *not* a complete solution. It produces the reduced file with a name like `[name of input file]_biber.bib` which implies that this could only work for very specific filename relations:

- Master BIB file (database): `somename_biber.bib`
- `\addbibresource{somename_biber.bib}`
- Document: `somename.tex`

However, this is very restrictive. Therefore I decided to write a small batch file (I use Windows) to solve all problems at once:

```
cd %~dp0
cp relative/path/to/MasterDB.bib reduced.bib
biber --output_file=reduced.bib --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve --strip_comments ../paper
biber ../paper

@echo off
echo.
echo Done!

if "%1"=="--background" exit
Pause
```

This assumes the above script to be located in `src/` and `paper.tex` with `addbibresource{src/reduced.bib}`.

The workflow is: Compile the `paper.tex`. Run the script. This updates/creates `src/reduced.bib` with the necessary data from `MasterDB.bib` *and* creates `paper.bbl`. Compile `paper.tex` again.

Comment: This is not a bad solution really. Just so it is clear - the .bcf is written by the first latex run and biber _reads_ the .bcf. Everything biber knows comes only from the .bcf, any biber.conf file and command line options.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I agree -- if you explained where I imply something wrong about the .bcf file I'd happily clarify it. Or maybe you just want to edit the answer? At the moment I don't see which is the wrong part you're referring to.