# JabRef: save selection of current library

Tags: jabref, export

I would like to save a selection from a library in JabRef 5.1.
This question was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82554/jabref-can-it-export-a-subset-of-the-bibliography-in-BibTeX-format).
However, the option "Save selected as..." is not present in my file menu.
The option "Save library as" saves the entire library, not just the selected entries.
The option "Export selected entries" saves to other formats.

How can I save a selection of entries in an existing library in a new library?

Comment: Select references > Ctrl+C (copy) > New Library > Ctrl+V  (paste) > Ctrl+S  (Save)

Comment: In Spanish installation there are also  the menu Archivo (File) > Exportar  (export) > Guardar seleccionados como BibTeX plano (Save selected references in the JabRef format that you are looking for).

Comment: Thanks. Ctrl-v in new library just freezes the program for some time without doing anything.

Comment: Try again, copy & paste between libraries  should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu File has what you need: File -> Export -> Save selected as plain BibTeX...
Happy JabRefing!

Comment: Thanks, but as explained in the question: the file menu does not have the option you are suggesting and the export selected entries does not save to plain bibtex.

Comment: @user39444 The JabRef libraries with tthe .bib extension are just plain bibtex files, so it is the option that you want

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks.